# DotNetNuke.SqlDataProvider method does not have an implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

> **Method 'AddFile' in type 'DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider' from
>   assembly 'DotNetNuke.SqlDataProvider, Version=6.2.1.11,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.**

A random error. My website has stopped working suddenly! Any idea on what might be going on?

Comment: Is your DNN self hosted or are you using some hosting provider?

Comment: Is it self hosted. It was a silly mistake. One of the several modules that I had installed on my local contained a different version of DotNetNuke.dll - It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

**It was a DotNetNuke.dll version problem. Nothing else.**